# CSS Slide and disapear animation

Tags: css, css-animations

I would like to make an animation for a popup that would slide to the left at the beginning and then disappear with the opacity after 8 seconds but I can't find how to do it.

What I have for now is

```css
@keyframes popup-anim {
  0% {
    right: -100%;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    right: 32px;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!, Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: With pure css it's not possible afaik. You need to use javascript and add a class after x milliseconds.  Are you using a frontend framework like angular or react?

Comment: I am using angular yeh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **first your popup container should be relative then only you can make animation with respect to container**
- **its difficult to guess on what html you are trying to fit the animation but however this should work for you**

```css
@keyframes popup-anim {
  0% {
    left: 0;
    
  }
  16% {
    left:-32px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.popup-container{
    position: relative;
    animation: popup-anim 8s forwards;
}
```